# Ruby Flickr API and Photosets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, flickr

I'm retrieving a list of an individual's photosets(albums) from flickr. How can I extract the id's from this array of hashes and then use [flickr.photosets.getPhotos](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html) to list the images in each album? I'm still learning Ruby and feeling very stuck on this. I'm grateful for any push in the right direction.

When I try adding `set.each do .. anything` to the `@photosets` block - I get a no method error for 'each'.

**photos_controller.rb**

```
require 'flickraw'

class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def index
    FlickRaw.api_key = ENV['FlickRaw_api_key']
    FlickRaw.shared_secret = ENV['FlickRaw_shared_secret']

    @photosets = flickr.photosets.getList(user_id: '67921947@N02').each do |set|
       set
    end
  end
end
```

**photos/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Listing photosets</h1>

<%= @photosets %>
```

**The current output**

Listing photosest

```
{  
  "id"   =>"72157633435549025",
  "primary"   =>"8720558709",
   "secret"   =>"d6f79d3d3c",
   "server"   =>"7395",
   "farm"   =>8,
   "photos"   =>"8",
   "videos"   =>0,
   "title"   =>"Poetry Project",
   "description"   =>"",
   "needs_interstitial"   =>0,
   "visibility_can_see_set"   =>1,
   "count_views"   =>"4",
   "count_comments"   =>"0",
   "can_comment"   =>0,
   "date_create"   =>"1368044794",
   "date_update"   =>"1368044886"
},
{  
   "id"   =>"72157633308505122",
   "primary"   =>"8674031898",
   "secret"   =>"8cd5722def",
   "server"   =>"8543",
   "farm"   =>9,
   "photos"   =>"22",
   "videos"   =>0,
   "title"   =>"Photo Midterm",
   "description"   =>"",
   "needs_interstitial"   =>0,
   "visibility_can_see_set"   =>1,
   "count_views"   =>"2",
   "count_comments"   =>"0",
   "can_comment"   =>0,
   "date_create"   =>"1366676884",
   "date_update"   =>"1366943480"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - here's the code that I used. This allows you to pull the information about an individual's albums(aka 'photosets') and then for the photos in each photoset.

**Controller**
    require 'flickraw'

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    FlickRaw.api_key = ENV['FlickRaw_api_key']
    FlickRaw.shared_secret = ENV['FlickRaw_shared_secret']

    @photosets = flickr.photosets.getList(user_id: '67921947@N02').map do |set|
      flickr.photosets.getPhotos(photoset_id: set['id']).photo.map do |photo|
        FlickRaw.url_b(photo)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<% @photosets[0].each do |image| %>
<%= image_tag image %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. If your intent is to output data of the photosets and their respective photos on your `index.html.erb`, you can try something like:

```
@photosets = flickr.photosets.getList(user_id: '67921947@N02').each do |set|
   set["photos"] = flickr.photosets.getPhotos(photoset_id: set["id"])
end
```

This will output something like:

```
{  
  "id"   =>"72157633435549025",
  "primary"   =>"8720558709",
   "secret"   =>"d6f79d3d3c",
   "server"   =>"7395",
   "farm"   =>8,
   "photos"   =>"8",
   "videos"   =>0,
   "title"   =>"Poetry Project",
   "description"   =>"",
   "needs_interstitial"   =>0,
   "visibility_can_see_set"   =>1,
   "count_views"   =>"4",
   "count_comments"   =>"0",
   "can_comment"   =>0,
   "date_create"   =>"1368044794",
   "date_update"   =>"1368044886"
   "photos" => [{"id" => "2484",
                 "secret"=>"123456", 
                 "server"=>"1", 
                 "title"=>"my photo", 
                 "isprimary"=>"0"},
                {"id" => "2483",
                 "secret" => "123456",
                 "server" => "1",
                 "title" => "flickr rocks",
                 "isprimary" => "1"}]
},
{ # etc... }
```

I am unsure what you mean by `sets.each do .. anything` doesn't work, as I don't see a `sets` in your codes.

Comment: That makes SO much sense to me ... but I'm getting this error undefined method `[]=' for #<FlickRaw::Response:0x007fcae6af22e8>

Comment: Any idea which parts of the codes trigger it? During `getList` or `getPhoto`?

Comment: I commented out everything after set["photos"] and there was no error.

Comment: Do I need to do anything in particular to parse the JSON? I'm using Rails 4.1.

Comment: Shouldn't need to do anything with JSON. Can you post whatever codes you have after `set["photos]`?

Comment: `@photosets = flickr.photosets.getList(user_id: '67921947@N02').each do |set|
      set["photos"] #= flickr.photosets.getPhotos(photoset_id: set["id"])` You can see the # where I commented out the assignment. @isim

Comment: Can you do `puts set["id"]` to see if it has any values?. Also, try use this [explorer](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photosets.getPhotos) to test your `photoset_id` to see if it returns any photos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63321/discussion-between-latazzajones-and-isim).